# Customing the newform.aspx of a list using jslink in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, office-365, jslink

How do I customise the newform.aspx of a list in SharePoint 2013 using JSLink?

A lot of examples seem to be for customising list views. I can't find anything that explains how to customise the new form for adding a new item to the list.

Basically I want to style the whole new form to match my look and feel.

Can someone please tell me how?

Comment: You have been given a lot of different answers and information about how to do this! Time to mark one as an answer!

Comment: JSLink might not be the best tool to **style** your form. JavaScript is usually used for behaviors, for look and feel consider using a stylesheet instead (css).

Answer (score 18):

You need to add a JSLink to the fields themselves (this means you need to either update the existing fields (by code or by PowerShell, harder in Office 365) or create your own field definition)

In that .js file you need to specify a number of methods that will override the standard functions, including View, DisplayForm, EditForm, NewForm.

Note that this will only change the style of every individual field!

[In MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163799.aspx) you can see an extensive example of how to customize every part of, in this case, a geolocation field.

I also found this [blog post](http://www.lestersconyers.com/custom-field-rendering-with-jslink/) that is very extensive and with lot's of great code examples.

Here is the basic structure of an .js for rendering a field (from MSDN above):

```
function _registerCustomGeolocationFieldTemplate() {

        var geolocationFieldContext = {};
        geolocationFieldContext.Templates = {};
        geolocationFieldContext.Templates.Fields = {

            'CustomGeolocationField': {
                'View': CustomGeolocationFieldTemplate.RenderGeolocationField,
                'DisplayForm': CustomGeolocationFieldTemplate.SPFieldGeolocation_Display,
                'EditForm': CustomGeolocationFieldTemplate.SPFieldGeolocation_Edit,
                'NewForm': CustomGeolocationFieldTemplate.SPFieldGeolocation_Edit
            }
        };
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(geolocationFieldContext);
    }
```

And the basic structure for a Callback method for your edit forms:

```
/// Function called to render the NewForm & EditForm view of the field
function editFunc(renderCtx) {
    var fieldHtml = '<select ';
    fieldHtml += 'id="myNiftySelect" onchange="moveValue(\'' + this.get_fieldId() + '\')">';
    fieldHtml += getSelectOptions(this.get_fieldValue());
    fieldHtml += '"</select>';
    fieldHtml += getStandardInputHtml(this, "hidden");
    return fieldHtml;
}
```

[from here](http://blog.aptillon.com/2012/10/12/custom-field-types-in-sharepoint-2013-apps/)

Answer (score 4):

newform.aspx uses an InfoPath form which you can customize with [InfoPath Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj602751.aspx) a lot easier than with JSLink.

Also depending on what "look and feel" changes you want to make, adding a custom CSS file to the master page can get you changes that will affect all InfoPath forms.

Comment: Well, I have my reasons for using JSLink. Sorry, but your answer is not helpful.

Comment: you should add the reason to your question

Comment: He was just pointing it out, no need to downvote his answer for that, right?

Answer (score 3):

Found this great article that i think will answer your question
[http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/13/sharepoint-2013-js-link-tutorial/](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/04/color-code-list-items-with-javascript-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/)

You will find there examples like:
[COLOR CODE LIST ITEMS WITH JAVASCRIPT (USING JS LINK) IN SHAREPOINT 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/04/color-code-list-items-with-javascript-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/)

And

[CUSTOMIZE LIST FORM FIELDS IN DISPLAY FORM (DISPFORM.ASPX) USING JS LINK IN SHAREPOINT 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/01/customize-list-form-fields-in-display-form-dispform-aspx-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013-2/)

And

[ADD TASK STATUS INDICATORS IN SHAREPOINT 2013 USING JS LINK](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/01/add-task-status-indicators-in-sharepoint-2013-using-js-link/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are [developing a web part as a sandboxed solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53109/porting-web-parts-to-office365-sharepoint-2013), you could [add a `<JSLink>` node](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevpreview/thread/8441b87f-44f2-4b35-b0b3-d7b6f19fce2c/) to your ListFormWebPart or XsltListViewWebPart definitions:

```
<WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
    <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>                        
    <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart</TypeName>
    <PageType>PAGE_NEWFORM</PageType>

    <JSLink>{path to JS file}</JSLink>

</WebPart>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, JSLink is more used for modifying the rendering of list VIEWS, not really for customizing complete list FORMS. If you want to change the visualisation of a specific field, OK, but for an entire form rendering? Use InfoPath, some JQuery or a custom application page to accomplish that...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you to take a look of a post of my collegue Chris O'Brien.
I wrote an amazing blog post about this topic:

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html

Answer (score 1):

Please check my [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82960/how-to-apply-jslink-to-lists-new-form-in-visual-studio/83426#83426) . Also you can use some logic for customize new/edit/view list forms controls.

Js file sample (add ID field in view form):

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("RenderIDField");

function RenderIDField() {
    debugger;
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + "ID" + "=([^&#]*)");
    var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    var TD1 = document.createElement("TD");
    TD1.className = "ms-formlabel";
    TD1.innerHTML = "<h3 class='ms-standardheader'>ID</h3>";
    var TD2 = document.createElement("TD");
    TD2.className = "ms-formbody";
    TD2.innerHTML = qs[1];
    var IdRow = document.createElement("TR");
    IdRow.appendChild(TD1);
    IdRow.appendChild(TD2);
    var ItemBody = GetSelectedElement(document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow"), "TABLE").getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
    ItemBody.insertBefore(IdRow, ItemBody.firstChild);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that you can refer to about using JS link with NewForm fields.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/06/24/customize-fields-in-newform-aspx-hidedisablepre-populate-with-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/