# Autocomplete with SPServices

Tags: jquery, spservices

This is my scenario

I have a list of clients on the root site collection.
www.mydomain.com/lists/clients

I have 17000 clients on that list.

Then I have other site collections, where I want to have a lookup field to the client list in the root site collection.
I know that by code I can create a lookupfield pointing to another site using the webguid.

I want to create an autocomplete field, simple select and multiple select with SPServices and showing multiple columns.

I am totally new to the SPServices world so I would a little bit of help with it.

1. Do I need to create a custom field type for this?
2. If not, then how can I attach that it shows the auto complete field for some specific lookup fields?
   This part is important to me, because I have 17000 site collections, and inside those site collections I will have multiple document libraries with a lookup field to the client list

Any source code to see an example of how to do it?

I saw this video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXYDBm28W_c&feature=endscreen&NR=1

It looks like the thing I need, but how can I inject that code in the NewForm.aspx specially if I have 17,000 site collections and on every site collection I have 50 document libraries where I want to have the autocomplete.

Thanks

Comment: Using JQuery and Sp services can be achievable, For large items can be minimized using Minimum length in text box.
https://jsharepoint.wordpress.com/2017/05/24/auto-complete-control-using-sp-services/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint you can build autocomplete in various ways.

Using SP2013 you can build an autocomplete field using

- Using the [SPClientAutoFill](http://msscorner.de/2013/08/12/building-an-autocomplete-field-in-sharepoint-2013-look-and-feel-spclientautofill/)control
- Using [Search](http://sharepointcandothat.com/creating-an-auto-complete-sharepoint-list-search-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- Use [JSLink](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64791/customing-the-newform-aspx-of-a-list-using-jslink-in-sharepoint-2013) to manipulate your new and edit form
- Use [Jquery autocomplete](http://chuvash.eu/2013/01/04/angular-jquery-ui-autocomplete/)

For SP2010 you can for instance use

- [Custom Picker dialog](http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2013/03/sharepoint-2010-create-a-custom-picker-with-dialog/)
- Use [Jquery autocomplete](http://chuvash.eu/2013/01/04/angular-jquery-ui-autocomplete/)

Comment: first 2 links are broken