# How to apply JSLink to List's New Form in Visual Studio?

Tags: 2013, jslink

I have content type say "Departments" and applying to the list named "All Departments", there is one field in content type that I want to apply js link to render it differently

I found some solution to render the fields differently using js link but in those articles they are suggesting to specify the  property of the field.

But I want to render the field in the single form's new form only. In other content types where the field is reference there should be normal rendering.

What should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should do this steps (for example):

Create New Field

```
<Field ID="{FFCDA660-279E-4581-B451-49365B002B1A}"
     Name="RequestStatus"
     DisplayName="Request status"
     Type="Choice"
     Required="TRUE"
     Overwrite="TRUE">
<CHOICES>
  <CHOICE>Open</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>In Progress</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Resolved</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Closed</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Reopened</CHOICE>
</CHOICES>
<Default>Open</Default>
```

Create new content type

```
  <ContentType ID="0x0100F1541A19429846C599622A6F63255D65"
               Name="Base Request Content Type"
               Overwrite="TRUE"
               Inherits="TRUE">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{FFCDA660-279E-4581-B451-49365B002B1A}" Name="RequestStatus" Required="TRUE"/>
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
```

Customize your list schema. Set **JSLink** attribute on the **Form** tags.

```
    <List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint"
      Title="Requests"
      DisableGridEditing="TRUE"
      FolderCreation="FALSE"
      NavigateForFormsPages="FALSE"
      EnableContentTypes="TRUE"
      Direction="$Resources:Direction;"
      Url="Lists/Requests"
      BaseType="0"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
            //Cointent types
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
            //Fileds
    </Fields>
    <Views>
            //Views
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" JSLink="~site/Lists/Files/RequestFormCRS.js" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

Js File sample

```
(function () {
    if (typeof SPClientTemplates === 'undefined')
        return;
    var fldCtx = {};
    fldCtx.Templates = {};
    fldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'RequestStatus': { 'NewForm': renderRequestStatus }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fldCtx);
}
)();

function renderRequestStatus(ctx) {
    var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);
    // logic for render html
    var controlHtml = "<input/>";

    formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function () {
    // get value logic
       var controlCurrentValue = "my value"; // extract value from control
       return controlCurrentValue;
    });

    return controlHtml;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply sir, but I am not finding the JSLink property in `<Form Type="NewForm.../>` what am I missing?

Comment: and also I am not getting the properties `DisableGridEditing` & `NavigateForFormsPages`

Comment: Visual studio 2012 IntelliSense don't know about this property (not documented properties). But it's work fine in my project.

Comment: Above two mentioned properties are required to set? those I am not finding?

Comment: `DisableGridEditing` &  `NavigateForFormsPages` are not required. It'is copy-paste from my code.:) You can remove it.

Comment: OK, thanks sir,
Where should the html code for the field be written to render field differently? Should it be in `formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function ()` with `return` statement?

Comment: I have made the js sample code more clear. Please check.

Comment: OK I am trying it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11643/discussion-between-users1100-and-artur-kukharevich)

Comment: JSLink property on the form tag is the way to go.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess one solution, not super good though, would be to add JSLink to the field. Then in the JSLink file you make a check on for example List name or URL of the current context (ctx).

It would allow you to change rendering only on the specific list.