# How to use JSLink attribute to hide a field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm trying to hide field C when field A equals B on the NewForm page. I used the JSLink attribute to add my scripts to the NewForm page.

```
 <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" JSLink="../Scripts/HideEndDateDuration.js|../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>
```

I get a warning that the JSLink attribute is not declared.

I ignore that and try to test if it works. Here is my jquery to hide the field :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection 
$("select[title='StartDate']").change(function() {
    if ($("select[title='StartDate']").val() == $("select[title='EndDate']").val()) 
    {
        $('nobr:contains("EndDateDuration")').closest('tr').hide();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $('nobr:contains("EndDateDuration")').closest('tr').show();
    }
  });
});
```

However nothing happens. When debugging in developer tools , the script is not even loaded when the form loads.

Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to load your JSLink reference like `~sitecollection/..../furtherURL/...` . E.g.`~sitecollection/siteassets/--/--/HideEndDateDuration.js`

Comment: In addition to above comment, i think that you need to have your jquery first as SharePoint renders the scripts from left to right in the jslink property.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have added an alert command before the $(document).ready(function() which executes. But the next jquery commands with the condition don't do anything.

Comment: Possible solution to check: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82960/how-to-apply-jslink-to-lists-new-form-in-visual-studio/83426#83426