# Using a document library, I want to have cascading columns

Tags: column, cascading

I have a document library and I have created two columns, one area and the other subarea. When a document is added, I want the person to select the area and then have the subarea list depend on the area selection. Is this possible?

Comment: I have a feeling that the 'Show in Groups' view might help too.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported out of the box.

You have a few options:

1. Use an InfoPath form to apply the filtering, but keep in mind that InfoPath is being discontinued in future versions
2. Use JS Link to customize the item forms, or create a custom field for it (this was better explored [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64791/customing-the-newform-aspx-of-a-list-using-jslink-in-sharepoint-2013) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d2ee01/sharepoint-2013-customize-a-custom-drop-down-field-by-using/))
3. Perhaps adapt the requirements a bit and use a Managed Metadata column where the person selects the sub-area (which is configured as a child node of the area - effectively selecting two metadatas in one)